# How to convert a single big number written in *.txt file into numpy array of its individual digits?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say, one have a `file.txt` with `1234567890` number written in it. Now, how one can convert this number into a `numpy.array`, ie. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]`?

Comment: `numpy.fromfile('file.txt', dtype='S1').astype(int)` But maybe you have to get rid of a line break or something..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to consider each character as a separate int, you can convert the string to `list` and then the list to np.array with `dtype=int`. Example -

```
with open('file') as f:
    narray = np.array(list(f.read()),dtype=int)
```

Example -

```
In [50]: np.array(list("1234567890"),dtype=int)
Out[50]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0])
```

Comment: And what if the number is so big that it extends `int64` range?

Comment: how is that possible when this would always only pick up single digits?

Comment: This way the 'number' is never an int, it is either a string, a list of strings, eventually an array of ints less than 10.

Comment: But that seems to be what the OP wants, given that there is no delimiter for the numbers, and according to OP's example each digit is to be considered a separate number.

Answer (score 0):

one solution might be to just load it into a string, get the length of the string and then get the char for each position up to the string length.

another one might be with pcre functions: in php it could be done by using preg_split on a string (example is in the docs: [see Example 2](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-split.php)

According to the site php2python, you should have a similar function in python: [php2python](http://www.php2python.com/wiki/function.preg-split/)